# get some char between two spacial char without space with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

**for example :**
i wanna get `*created by:*` and `*M*` and don't get `*proudly *` or `* proudly*`(have space near `*` or `*` ) with regex in javascript.

```js
//not work
let c = "RegExr was *created by:* gskinner.com, and is *proudly *hosted by *M*edia Temple.";
const regExr = /(\*\*)([^\s|\*])+([^\s|\*])(\*\*)/g;
```

this work ( tnx for `@Wiktor Stribiżew` )

```
const regExr = /\*([^*]*[^*\s])\*/g;
```

but not working for : `* proudly*`

i changed to -> `/\*([^*\s]*[^*\s])\*/g`

but don't get -> `*created by:*`

Comment: Maybe a negative lookbehind would help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions

Comment: i have two problem 1.in this case i can't get one or two word -> like `*M*` 2.if exist space between to word -> like `*created by:*`

Comment: `/(\*)(.+?)\1/g` match with string and filter the array and check if space before last `*` contain space or not.

Comment: What about using two regex? One to match all strings inside `*` and another to filter out the invalid ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
let c = "RegExr was *created by:* gskinner.com, and is *proudly *hosted by *M*edia Temple. And * proudly* presents...";
const regExr = /\*([^\s*](?:[^*]*[^*\s])?)\*/g;
// Getting all matches with asterisks
console.log(c.match(regExr));
// Or, only the contents between
console.log(Array.from(c.matchAll(regExr), x=>x[1]));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VHMp8I/2).

*Details*

- `\*` - a `*` char
- `([^\s*](?:[^*]*[^*\s])?)` - Group 1: any one char other than whitespace and asterisk, then an optional occurrence of zero or more chars other than `*` and then a char other than whitespace and `*`
- `\*` - a `*` char.

A variation of a two-step approach that should be a bit more versatile than the above one-step approach (especially in case of unbalanced amount of asterisks):

```js
let c = "RegExr was *created by:* gskinner.com, and is *proudly *hosted by *M*edia Temple.";
const regExr = /\*([^*]*)\*/g;
console.log(c.match(regExr).filter( x => !/\s\*$/.test(x)) )
console.log(Array.from(c.matchAll(regExr), x=>x[1]).filter(x => x == x.trim()) )
```

Comment: this not work `\*([^\s*]*[^*\s])\*` why? (for ->`created by:`  )

Comment: I do not want to take (start with space) either

Comment: @H.jalali  Then you could use `\*([^\s*](?:[^*]*[^*\s])?)\*`. I updated the solution.

Answer (score 4):

First, [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) all result that is in between `*` and then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the result that doesn't contain space before last (`*`)

```js
let c ="RegExr was *created by:* gskinner.com, and is *proudly *hosted by *M*edia Temple.";
const regExr = /(\*)(.+?)\1/g;

const result = c.match(regExr).filter((el) => !el.match(/\*.+\s\*/));

console.log(result);
```